# Can reduce the rewriteRule to one rule from multiple RewriteConds for 301 in htaccess?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I am doing 301 redirects for old sites to a single site, rather then having to add the same RewriteRule more then once, is there a way to say write it once? that way i just need to add the rewriteCond once?

My current code

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newSite.local%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite2.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newSite.local%2 [L,R=301]
```

I tried :
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite.local [NC]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite2.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newSite.local%2 [L,R=301]
```

but that doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite.local [NC, OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Oldsite2.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newSite.local%2 [L,R=301]
```

this will change the implicit logical and of `RewriteCond` to a logical or.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond's are normally 'AND's, however you can change them to 'OR's byt adding the `OR` option to the end.

[More info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)