# Force HTTPS w/ Load Balancer and without (.htaccess rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code as a rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This seems to work great with and without a ssl terminated load balancer. My question:

are the 2 rewrite conditions "ORed" and Anded". If I remove `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` I get an infinite redirect when accessing the web server directly. (I need this to work while DNS propagates)

I am just confused by the rule

Answer (score 2):

The rewritecond's should be or:ed as only one of the conditions will normally be true at any one time. This however would need additional syntax in the form of the OR directive: [Can reduce the rewriteRule to one rule from multiple RewriteConds for 301 in htaccess?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109949/can-reduce-the-rewriterule-to-one-rule-from-multiple-rewriteconds-for-301-in-hta)

The first rewritecond checks to see if the protocol used by the connection is not https. If this resolves as true, a redirect to https is sent to the client.

The second rewritecond checks to see if ssl has already been terminated (for example in the load balancer), at which an x-forwarded-proto http header would have been injected with the value of https. If the header value isn't https, a redirect to https is sent to the client.

Removing the first condition whilst connecting directly to the server will result in a redirection loop.

Removing the second condition whilst connecting through the load-balancer(or whichever external node does the termination) will also result in a redirection loop.

I would try(untested as I'm on an iphone):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I think I finally understand the problem. The first condition will always be TRUE in the case of using the load balancer, so the OR will cause a redirection loop. The second condition will always be true in the case of the direct access. So if they are both true, then we know we have to do a redirect, otherwise it is using https already. If they are OR'ed then we will have an infinite redirect loop

Comment: Silly me! You're right of course! I'm glad you got it sorted though, write your own answer with the relevant details and I'll upvote it.